# How to insert an intro in console.log() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, console.log, paragraph

I would like to print some text using console.log(). I have several lines, a for each one I have used a console.log(). I would like to create 2 paragraphs. How could I do it? Thanks

```js
 console.log("1 : Lister les contacts"); //paragraph 1
 console.log("2 : Ajouter un contact");  //paragraph 1
 console.log("0 : Quitter");  //paragraph 1
 console.log("Choisissez une option :")); //paragraph 2
```

Comment: you want it to be done by using console.log only twice? is this the question?

Comment: What do you mean by "paragraph"? Are you asking how to print a blank line?

Comment: how are you going to read and act upon une option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log("1 : Lister les contacts"); //paragraph 1
console.log("2 : Ajouter un contact"); //paragraph 1
console.log("0 : Quitter"); //paragraph 1
console.log(""); //paragraph 1
console.log("Choisissez une option :"); //paragraph 2
```

Or you can use `\n` to break the line and use two time `\n\n` to break two line:

```js
console.log("   p1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \n\n   p2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log("1 : Lister les contacts"); //paragraph 1
console.log("2 : Ajouter un contact");  //paragraph 1
console.log("0 : Quitter");  //paragraph 1
console.log("\n\nChoisissez une option :"); //paragraph 2​
```

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is a new line, and `\t` is a tab (indent).  Also, you can "concatenate" strings (basically adding them together.

```
var paragraph1 = "1 : Lister les contacts\n";
paragraph1 = paragraph1 + "2 : Ajouter un contact\n";
paragraph1 = paragraph1 + "0 : Quitter\n");
var paragraph2 = "Choisissez une option :";

console.log(paragraph1 + "\n" + paragraph2);
```

This will result in what you showed with no indents, and a line between the paragraphs. Note: separate console.log() calls are always on different lines, so keeping them on separate console logs you wouldn't need that `\n` at the end.

Also, you could add a `\t` to the beginnnig of each line in the list to help separate it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\r\n` in between your lines to add a new line so that one call of `console.log` prints the first 3 lines.

```js
//paragraph 1
console.log("1 : Lister les contacts\r\n2 : Ajouter un contact\r\n0 : Quitter");
//paragraph 2
console.log("Choisissez une option :"); //paragraph 2
```

You also had an extra `)` on the last `console.log()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template literals for multiline String. A template literal is delimited by backticks:

```js
console.log(`1 : Lister les contacts
2 : Ajouter un contact  
0 : Quitter
         
         `);   //paragraph 1
         
console.log('Choisissez une option :');   //paragraph 2
```

Comment: For completeness just be aware it won't work on some older browsers.. eg. IE11

Comment: @yezzz agreed. Anyway console logs are for developers and older browser support is not an issue here. :D

Answer (score 0):

I am a French speaker and think you want something like this. You just don't know how to explain it.

```html
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label">Choisissez une option :</label>
        <div class="select">
            <select class="myoptions">
                <option value="1">1 : Lister les contacts</option>
                <option value="2">2 : Ajouter un contact</option>
                <option value="3">0 : Quitter</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: No. Its a different question.

Comment: The Question is about console.log() and not about HTML forms. I don't think it has anything to do with language. By the way, you have written perfect English (y)

Comment: @Abhi Andhariya - Thanks Abhi. My English is good because I live in United States. I teach Javascript in French and have answered similar questions several times.